# How can I use matcaffe in Windows?

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

To use caffe in MATLAB, i need matcaffe.

The manual tells me to run "make all matcaffe"

But it does not tell where to command.

I command "run make all" matcaffe by running cmd from the cafe root folder where caffe.exe exists.

But there is an error saying "There is nothing to do for matcaffe"

Is there a clear, specific, and accurate description of how matcaffe can be run?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official branch for caffe on Windows. [BVLC/caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows)

Follow the steps in that repository, like the below

```
C:\Projects> git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
C:\Projects> cd caffe
C:\Projects\caffe> git checkout windows
:: Edit any of the options inside build_win.cmd to suit your needs
C:\Projects\caffe> scripts\build_win.cmd
```

If you got all the tools successfully installed, you will be able to build it successfully. Then you could find a `.mex64` file under the `caffe/matlab` folder. 
Simply add that directory into matlab, you can use matcaffe then.